# Failed to create remote driver... org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session when running code from Jenkins

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

I have 2 source codes I use (both are exactly the same):

1. Local JAVA code
2. Jenkins job with the same Java code.

When running from Jenkins I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: 
Failed to create remote driver... org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: 
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or 
browser start-up failure.
```

But when running the same code from my local computer to the same selenium grid - everything works just fine.

Some facts:

- I am using selenium Selenium Grid v.3.141.59 on
  http://x.x.x.x:5555/grid/console
- The java on my local computer is v1.8
- The JAVA on Jenkins server is v11
- The chromeDriver I am using in the grid is v87.0 due to needs of R&D.

I am at a point where me and my dev ops team are somehow lost... tried almost everything without success, like checking ports, firewalls, versions... etc'.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Turns out that 1 of Jenkins's plugins was the reason for the job not to communicate with anything outside Jenkins, HTTP, HTTPS and therefore was blocking the connection to the hub.

Answer (score -1):

try running the Jenkins script as Administrator